# Super or subscript notation on the left hand side of a symbol?

Tags: soft-question, notation

Are there any commonly used notations with super or subscripts on the left hand side of the symbol? or on both sides of a symbol? If so, then what is the latex for having sup/sub script on left or both sides of a symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I often use a superscript on the left hand side to indicate the order of a tensor, e.g.

$$^4 \boldsymbol{C}$$

for the fourth-order stiffness tensor. Additionally, here in the Netherlands the base of a logarithm is often written as a superscript on the left hand side, e.g.

$$^2 \log 8 = 3$$

but I don't use this notation anymore as it tends to confuse people.

To conclude, a $\LaTeX$ related note: the superscript can be moved closer to the symbol by using `\!`, resulting in $^2 \! \log 8 = 3$.

Comment: I do the same for pre-superscripts, but often put braces instead of leaving a blank: `{}^3 G_1^2`.  `\!` is new and useful to me.

Answer (score 3):

$_nC_r$ is sometimes used for $n\choose r$. I did this with _nC_r in dollar signs.

Comment: Thanks, I forgotton about that, what about supersript on left or something with a sup/sub script on all sides, has anyone seen anything like that?

Comment: I have also seen $^nC_r$ used.

Comment: You can also attach superscripts and subscripts to an empty group `{}`.  For example, `{}_nC_r` produces ${}_nC_r$.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen spectral sequences labelled as

$${}^{II} E^n_{p,q} $$

I've seen it suggested that one should use `{}^a B` to get ${}^aB$ rather than simply `^a B`. There's probably something error prone about the latter, but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 2):

[Hypergeometric functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) are written $_2 F _1$, which is `_2F_1` in LaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

In math mode, TeX (almost) just ignores spaces, so if you write `x  ^2 B` you get $x  ^2 B$, while `x  {}^2B` gives $x  {}^2B$. [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334/non-kludgey-left-subscripts) they recommend using the tensor package.

Answer (score 1):

Tetration—the operation that is iterated exponentiation much like exponentiation is iterated multiplication—is often notated with a superscript before the number. For example:
$$
4^{4^{4^4}}=^4\!\!4
$$
The same thing could be shown using Knuth's up-arrow notation though:
$$
^44=4\uparrow\uparrow4
$$
and I'm not sure how accepted the former notation is anymore.